# SuperTest times out when response is HTTP 400

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6, async-await, mocha.js, supertest

While creating some tests with SuperTest and Mocha:

```
import supertest from 'supertest';
import { should } from 'chai';
import app from '../app.mjs';

const request = supertest(app);
should();

describe('HTTP GET', () => {
    describe('/api/v1/songs', () => {
        it('When request has no parameters, then response Status-Code should be 200 (OK)', async () => {
            const response = await request.get('/api/v1/songs');
            response.statusCode.should.equal(200);
        });
    });
    describe('/api/v1/songs/year/:year', () => {
        it('When parameter is an unknown year, then response Status-Code should be 400 (Bad Request)', async () => {
            const response = await request.get('/api/v1/songs/year/1776');
            response.statusCode.should.equal(400);
        });
        it('When parameter is an valid year, then response Status-Code should be 200 (OK)', async () => {
            const response = await request.get('/api/v1/songs/year/1977');
            response.statusCode.should.equal(200);
        });
        it('When parameter is an valid year, then response should include songs matching that year', async () => {
            const response = await request.get('/api/v1/songs/year/1977');
            response.body.forEach((song) => {
                song.should.have.property('year', 1977);
            });
        });
    });
});
```

I've noticed that curiously the ones timing out are those returning `HTTP 400`:

```
HTTP GET
/api/v1/songs
  ✔ When request has no parameters, then response Status-Code should be 200 (OK)
/api/v1/songs/year/:year
  1) When parameter is an unknown year, then response Status-Code should be 400 (Bad Request)
  ✔ When parameter is an valid year, then response Status-Code should be 200 (OK)
  ✔ When parameter is an valid year, then response should include songs matching that year
```

The error message doesn't add much context:

```
  1) HTTP GET
       /api/v1/songs/year/:year
         When parameter is an unknown year, then response Status-Code should be 400 (Bad Request):
     Error: Timeout of 2000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves.
```

I'm not sure if there is something else (e.g. try/catch) that needs to be done to have it working properly?

Answer (score 0):

I've been able to solve the issue: it turned out that the controller action was not calling `.end()` after `res.status(400)`.

Comment: Hi! I have the same kind of error. Do you mind explaining me what is the `.end()` who was not called please?

Comment: Yes! So the controller responses should have the tailing `.end()`.
The complete implementation: https://github.com/nanotaboada/node-samples-express-restful/blob/master/controllers/songsController.mjs